# How do I prove the following inequality? (Problem from Spivak's Calculus.)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove that if $$|x - x_0| < \min \bigg(\frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}, 1\bigg) \quad \text{and} \quad |y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$$

then $|xy - x_0y_0|<\epsilon$?

I assume I have to start with something like $(x - x_0)(y-y_0)$ to get to writing $xy - x_0y_0$, but all I have so far is that

$$|(x-x_0)(y-y_0)| \le |xy - x_0y_0| + |xy_0-2x_0y_0 + x_0y|,$$

and I can't seem to get any further than that and I'd appreciate some help with this problem.

Comment: Probably a stupid question to ask.... but does the $\epsilon$ have to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with 
$$xy-x_0y_0=(x-x_0)y+x_0(y-y_0)
$$
then $$|xy-x_0y_0|\le |x-x_0| |y| + |x_0| |y-y_0| .
$$
Can you continue from there?